# Connect usb cable and waiting for device problem in bootloader

Tags: rooting, bootloader, motorola

I wanted to unlock the bootloader for my motorola moto g 3rd gen.

I get to the step where I put my phone into fastboot mode. On the bottom of my screen in fastboot mode, it says 'connect usb data cable' – when my usb is already connected.

I tried `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server` but it never helped. I also tried changing ports, cables and even tried `adb devices` command every ten seconds. None of these worked.

On the PC in *Device Manager* I can see my device as adb. I have tried many things, but am out of ideas now. Please, can someone help me with this?

Comment: Just a note: in bootloader, there's no such thing as ADB – so `adb devices` won't find anything, and `adb kill-server` won't have any effect. Only [fastboot](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/fastboot/info) commands will do here, e.g. `fastboot devices` should find your Moto.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not entirely sure if it matters in fast boot but to use Aden services normally you need to enable USB debugging in developer options, start the server, then in another terminal type `adb usb`. This listens to USB ports and checks for any open connections. Also, some phones don't like it but my nexus requires unmounting before I use adb.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think that helps: See my comment on the question itself. There's no such thing as ADB when in [fastboot](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/fastboot/info) / bootloader mode, and the "USB Debugging" settings won't have effect either as Android isn't even loaded. As the name "bootloader" suggests, it comes *before* the OS is loaded; it's rather comparable to your PC's BIOS. So I'm afraid your answer is completely unrelated.

Comment: Ah ok thanks I'm an iOS developer primarily so I know more iOS than Android xD

Comment: I took that as trigger to update our [bootloader tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/bootloader/info) ;) Also check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booting#SPL), which explains the bootloader aka SPL (Secondary Program Loader).